# How Do I change existing theme to a new one without losing content?

Tags: theming

Can someone lead me to documentation that explains how I can change an existing Drupal theme to a new one without losing all of my existing content?

The blog I manage is currently set up on the Omega 7.x 3.1 framework, with a semi-custom subtheme. We would like to install a new theme with more out of the box capabilities and a better design but it is important that the two years of published articles are maintained in the current chronological order and with their image content, etc.

Any help finding the instructions on how to accomplish this will be a great help.

Best wishes from Spain!

Answer (score 2):

Technically you won't loose any of your content since Drupal's *theme layer* is seperate from the content. Depending on how your previous theme is set up (templates, theme functions, etc) it can however happen, that the **display** of some of your content might not work / work differently in another theme.

A good starting point for learning more about Drupal's *theme layer* is the [***Theming Guide*** which is part of the Community Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme) at drupal.org. A more advanced view on theming can be found in the chapter **'Themes'** of the book *Drupal 7 – the Essentials* which you can actually [read online](https://www.drupal.org/node/1585772) at drupal.org.

Comment: Many thanks for the response! It looks like I am going to do some reading this weekend. :)

Comment: hehe – reading is always a good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

However....
If any one involved in building that site cut any corners and placed content directly INTO the theme files, then you might lose content when switching themes.

The more common example of this is having TPL files where the developer hand coded content in there instead of creating nodes or other entities.

If your site was built with Best Practices in mind, then you can switch themes as much as you like and never lose any content.

Curious... What theme are you thinking of going to?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm looking at a few from Theme Forest but still haven't decided. Would be something along the lines of the Copper theme and only used for the blog features. Do you have any suggestions?

This is the current theme we are working with and it needs a facelift urgently: http://blog.lesroches.es